# undefined reference to static variable, no class

Tags: c++

I know similar question have been posted all over, but all the ones I've looked at assume that the variable exists in a class. I have tried a similar thing, just removing the class part, but still get the same error:

```
TestController.cpp:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `vio::HORIZONTAL_MOTOR'
```

vio.h

```
#ifndef VIO_H
#define VIO_H
namespace vio
{
        ...
        extern TransistorTuple HORIZONTAL_MOTOR;
        extern TransistorTuple FRONT_MOTOR;
        extern TransistorTuple BACK_MOTOR;
        ...
```

vio.cpp

```
...
void vio::initialize()
{
        // Define variables
        vio::TransistorTuple HORIZONTAL_MOTOR;
        vio::TransistorTuple FRONT_MOTOR;
        vio::TransistorTuple BACK_MOTOR;
        ...
}
```

TestController.cpp

```
...
void test::moveChair()
{
        // Define variables
        vio::TransistorTuple HORIZONTAL_MOTOR;
        vio::TransistorTuple FRONT_MOTOR;
        vio::TransistorTuple BACK_MOTOR;
        ...
}
```

The definition works fine in vio.cpp but when I do the same thing in TestController.cpp, it gives an error. I am including vio.h in TestController.

Comment: Since this is obviously some embedded code, the compiler used would be helpful (many embedded compilers suck ;) ). But... in vio.cpp, you should have the same ``namespace vio { ... }`` statement and then you do not need the prefix for each of the variables. Maybe then, your compiler will understand...

Comment: I'm compiling with cmake on linux. vio.cpp is linking fine, its the other one I don't know whats happening with.

Comment: Off topic a bit: Usually it is a bad idea to use global variables. Maybe you want to re-think the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

If the member variable is static, you need to provide a *static* (not in any function) declaration for it:

```
vio::TransistorTuple HORIZONTAL_MOTOR = (some value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `vio.h` you declare `extern` variables within the namespace `vio`.

As such, if you wish to **define** those variables in `vio.cpp`, you cannot do that inside the `vio::initialize()` function.

Normally, vio.cpp would look similar to this:

```
#include <vio.h>
namespace vio {
     TransistorTuple HORIZONTAL_MOTOR = { /* however that type is initialized */ };
     void initialize() {
         // whatever this function does when called...
     }
}
```

The code above would make `HORIZONTAL_MOTOR` a so called `initvar`. The startup code before main(), often called something like `crt0.cpp` or similar, which is usually provided with the compiler tool chain is responsible to get that right (to call constructors of initvars).

Now, depending on your tool chain, you might have to fix your project configuration. Sometimes, people use some old C related startup code which "forgets" to do the initializing. But if that is so in your case, you cannot work around that mistake with a custom `initialize()` function. You need to fix your project / build tool chain.